# Missing headers in IIS6 (ColdFusion, and possibly other languages too)

Tags: java, coldfusion, iis-6, http-headers

I'm using ColdFusion to access the 'Authorization' header value passed from IIS.
I have this working with no problems on IIS7 however in IIS6 the header is simply not available to me in ColdFusion.
I've tried using JAVA to access the header, and I've read elsewhere that people have had similar problems with ASP.

Strangely, if I look at the headers in FireBug for FireFox, the Authorization header is visible there, so I know that the IIS server is passing the value back - I just can't make any use of it in my code!

Does anyone have a solution?

Code example:

```
<!--- Force authorisation --->
<cfheader statuscode="401" statustext="Unauthorized" />
<cfheader name="WWW-Authenticate" value="basic realm=""API""" />
<cfoutput>
    #getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader('Authorization')# <!--- Blank on IIS6 --->
    <cfdump var="#getHTTPRequestData()#"> <!--- Authorization header missing on IIS6 --->
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling both "Basic" and "Anonymous" authentication within IIS?  It's possible that without Basic enabled, IIS 6 won't expose that header to the underlying apps.

Comment: Alas, yes... I've tried various combinations. In fact in my IIS7 setup which is working correctly, I don't have Basic enabled. I found when Basic was enabled on the IIS6 server, two separate authentication windows appeared - one with the domain as the realm and the other with the specific realm I set.
The only difference that I can see, is that on the IIS6 server, the anonymous access has a username and password attached, so that anonymous hits use a specific windows account.

Comment: Well, I know that usually the authentication information is made available via cgi.auth_user.  Have you tried just using that?

Comment: It's not available in the CGI scope - in fact as far as I'm aware, the getPageContext() Java method is what's used to populate CF's CGI variables, so if I can't get at the data with getPageContext(), I won't be able to get at it in the CGI scope either.

Comment: You might have to add a module to IIS to allow this header to be available.  Maybe this one? http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/